# ceiling fan on after shutting off power

Tags: electrical, ceiling, fans, voltage

Trying to remove a ceiling fan upstairs.  I shut off the breakers for upstairs, and everything turned off - except the ceiling fan is still running. None of the rooms upstairs have power. How is the ceiling fan still running? I shut off a couple of other breakers (dining room, kitchen) and it is still running. I did not shut off the power to the whole house.

Comment: Some will coast for a long time, but if it's actually powered up, you just haven't found the right breaker for it yet. Often circuit layout only makes any sense to the person that did it, or things are hung off some other circuit in a nonsensical manner. Just keep switching things off until you find it (shut down any non-battery computers first, of course)

Comment: It is on a different breaker.  Keep turning off breakers till the fan stops.  Make sure there is no power in that box after.

Answer (score 2):

What cip659 said in a comment is *the* answer.

> It is on a different breaker. Keep turning off breakers till the fan stops. Make sure there is no power in that box after.

You turned off the breaker(s) based on their labeling, but the labeling is incomplete and/or inaccurate, so you have to keep going until you find the one that this fan connects to. Once you find it, update the labeling.

Unfortunately, this is *very* common in older houses and can be common in newer houses that had A) erratic electricians or B) DIY work prior to your arrival.

Also, when the fan stops with a breaker off, be sure to double check the wiring in the switch box *and* the ceiling box to ensure that *all* the power is off. It's not uncommon for there to be more than one circuit live in a box and you don't want to zap yourself thinking you got it all when you didn't...